# Customize a select with font-awesome

Tags: css, select, font-awesome

This is what I have actually:

## HTML

```
<label class="select">
  <select name="email" id="email">
    <option>aaaa</option>
    <option>aaaa</option>
    <option>aaaa</option>
    <option>aaaa</option>
    <option>aaaa</option>
    <option>aaaa</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

## CSS

```
.cforms select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;   
}


.select {
    position:relative;   
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    margin-top:40px;
}

.select:after {
  content: "\f0dc";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: #000;
  padding:8px;
  position:relative;
  right:35px;
  top:0px;
  background:red;
  z-index:-1;
  width:10%;
  line-height:10%;
}
```

## Problem

Actually, no arrows appears near my select.

Could you please help me with this.

I searched on the web for examples, but I can't make it works.

Thanks.

Comment: `input`s such as `select` elements cannot have pseudo-elements AFAIK

Answer (score 33, accepted):

maybe so

**1) Font Awesome 4**

```css
.select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 40px;    
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

select{       
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;       
    width: 240px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.select:after {
    content:"\f0dc";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;      
    pointer-events: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label class="select">
    <select name="email" id="email">
        <option>aaaa1</option>
        <option>aaaa2</option>
        <option>aaaa3</option>
        <option>aaaa4</option>
        <option>aaaa5</option>
        <option>aaaa6</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

**2) Font Awesome 5**

```css
.select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 40px;    
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

select{       
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;       
    width: 240px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.select:after {
    content:"\f35a";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;      
    pointer-events: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<label class="select">
    <select name="email" id="email">
        <option>aaaa1</option>
        <option>aaaa2</option>
        <option>aaaa3</option>
        <option>aaaa4</option>
        <option>aaaa5</option>
        <option>aaaa6</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Really important thing for me in this answer is `pointer-events: none;`, because it prevents breaking of click events!

Comment: we can not use `pseudo-elements` on `<select>`. We must use `label` to wrap it. That's great idea and your answer

Comment: If using Font Awesome 5, you'll need to use a different font-family. Most likely `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"`, but there are 4 different options now. See here for more details: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: I've used it to customize a form on Contact Form 7 (WordPress) and, instead of adding a label on the form (it breaks my layout), I've used the class of the surrounding span that CF7 appends around the select to apply the after styles on it. Great!